# Naming a program in EV3 software?

Tags: software, ev3

I have figured out how name a project but cannot figure out how to rename a program.

Answer (score 4):

Just double click on program's name in the tab.

Comment: What about on computer
Philo
Please anyone respond

Comment: The LEGO code double click speed requirement is set very short.
If I really concentrate on clicking quickly --- it works.